# Passing Parameters To a Report Through The URL in Salesforce 1

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am Passing Parameters To a Report Through The URL (On account object using custom link) which is working in salesforce internally. but it is not working in case of salesforce 1.

I am using custom link on account which will redirect to a report like:

```
/00OC0000005ZIVk?pv0={!Account.QAD_ID__c}
```

But the same is not working in Salesforce 1.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: URL hacking doesn't work in salesforce1

Answer (score 1):

Passing parameters to the URL is not supported both in Salesforce 1 and Lightning.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187793&language=en_US&type=1

Answer (score 1):

Passing parameters to standard pages (including Reports) is not yet possible in Salesforce1.

To get around this, at present, you'd need to create the Reports/Charts using Visualforce. (Visualforce pages can accept parameters.) Here's a reference for Charting with Visualforce: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting.htm

There's an Idea on the Idea Exchange you can vote on as well, to encourage the Product Team to support parameters on standard pages: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DjkfAAC